# prolog,very simple dcg syntax

Tags: syntax, prolog, dcg

I am trying to understand the basic syntax of prolog and dcg but it's really hard to get ahold of proper information on  the really basic stuff. Take a look at the code below, I basically just want to achieve something like this:

```
Output = te(a, st).

Code: 
    test(te(X,Y)) --> [X], test2(Y).
    test2(st(_X)) --> [bonk]. 

    ?- test(Output, [a, bonk],[]).
    Output = te(a, st(_G6369)).
```

Simply what I want to do is to add the the word 'st' at the end, and the closest way I've managed is by doing this but unfortunately st is followed a bunch of nonsense, most likely because of the singleton `_X`. I simply want my `Output` to contain like: `te(a, st).`

Comment: It is much safer to call a non-terminal via `phrase/2`. Your query should thus rather read: `?- phrase(test(Output), [a,bonk]).`

Comment: +1: it's funny to read answers that *bonk*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to accept input of the form `[Term, bonk]` and obtain `te(Term,st)` you should change `test/2` to accept bonk a return `st`:

```
test(te(X,Y)) --> [X], test2(Y).
test2(st) --> [bonk].


?-  test(Output, [a, bonk],[]).
Output = te(a, st).
```

Comment: Well now I certainly feel silly! I could've sworn I tested without any argument, in fact, that was pretty much the sole reason for why I came here to Stackoverflow! I must've made some kind of error earlier when I tried it myself because as the solutions here have explained, it does indeed work.

Answer (score 1):

As you said, st is followed by "a bunch of nonsense" because of `_X` (basically, _G6369 is the internal 'name' of the variable and since the variable remains uninstantiated prolog displays it; try `print(X), X=3, print(X).`

Anyway, you can simply remove `(_X)` since you can have anything you want as an argument:

```
test(te(X,Y)) --> [X], test2(Y).
test2(st) --> [bonk].
```

Of course, if you don't actually have `bonk`'s in your input and you simply want to add a `st` at the end you can simplify it even more:

```
test(te(X,st)) --> [X].
```

Or if you have `bonk`'s:

```
test(te(X,st)) --> [X,bonk].
```

Finally, it is generally suggested to use [phrase/3](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=phrase/3) or [phrase/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=phrase/2) instead of adding the arguments manually.